# No GUI in Ubuntu 14.04.2 after attempting to install Ark Server

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I was attempting to follow [this](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Dedicated_Server_Setup#Linux) guide on how to set up an Ark Survival Evolved Server (including the bits recommended on Steam's website). I now get a black screen with no access from the Ubuntu machine.

I'm guessing it was one of these tasks that botched Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

or

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t experimental install libc6-dev
```

When first used the machine everything seemed fine. However, when I attempted to change my sound settings I noticed a lot of problems. Basically they wont open. Also, VLC wouldn't run.

I restarted for reasons that are beyond me at the moment. Now I have no GUI at all but I can still connect through SSH. Any ideas How I can begin to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Use Ctrl+Shift+F1 and see if a tty opens up and login with your credentials. Let me know if it works. Are you using unity?  If so,  try this : sudo service lightdm restart

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F1 doesnt do anything that I can see. Think: display doesn't work. When running the command through ssh command I got "stop: Unknown instance:" 
"start: Job failed to start"

Comment: Are you running on open sourced graphic drivers or did you install a manufacturer specific one?

Comment: Did you try removing the packages and rebooting?

Comment: I tried rolling back through ssh. I'm now really in a bind because it updated my network adapter and botched the installation. Opening a new one on super user that is more specific to my current issues.